# How to save information of a csv-File in a list

Tags: java

I wanted to ask how I can load information of a csv-file in a list. I don't have much until now so a little help would be nice if possible. What I tried until now is to get the file but I'm not sure if it's right because I'm not that good at File I/O. After that I stuck at how to save it in a list.

```
List<GameCharacter> characters;

static void loadTextFile(String textFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //textFile = String.valueOf(new File("C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Temp1_2022_WHP.zip/resources/characters.csv"));
        textFile = "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Temp1_2022_WHP.zip/resources/characters.csv";
        FileInputStream d = new FileInputStream(textFile);
    }
```

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have any limitations on what you can use and what can't but did you try using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) library?

You can then read it like this

```
  try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file.csv"))) {
      List<String[]> r = reader.readAll();
      r.forEach(x -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x)));
  }
```

This will give you a list of array of strings which will contain all the values for each line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Scanner` like this

```
textFile = "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Temp1_2022_WHP.zip/resources/characters.csv";
List<List<String>> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("textFile"));) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        mylist.add(getRecordFromLine(scanner.nextLine()));
    }
}
```

You can also use `BufferedReader` in java.io like the following

```
textFile = "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Temp1_2022_WHP.zip/resources/characters.csv";

List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader bffuerReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("textFile"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = bffuerReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            myList.add(Arrays.asList(values));
        }
    }
```